# Format double number without thousand separator?

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone know the way to format a double value to a String without thousand separator (In Swift - ios).

Note: I need to consider the current locale as some european languages use comma (,) as decimal separator. for example german languange write 12.50 as 12,50.

So if the double value is 1250.25

```
English-uk : 1250.25
German     : 1250,25
```

if I use following two ways (Whn english UK) I am getting the value as (1,212.50). BUT I want to format the value to String without thousant separator. So in this case 1212.50

```
var testOne = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.2f", 1212.50)

var testTwo = String(format: "%.2f", locale: NSLocale.currentLocale(), 1212.50)
```

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the NSNumberFormatter on the number and explicitly set the grouping separator to empty string:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")  // locale determines the decimal point (. or ,); English locale has "."
formatter.groupingSeparator = ""  // you will never get thousands separator as output
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
let result = formatter.stringFromNumber(1233.99)  // you will always get string 1233.99
```

Comment: Hi Lubos, Thanks for the answer. But in here it rounds up and provide an integer answer (1234). In my case I need  the double value always with 2 decimal format (converted as a string).

Comment: In that case you need to set some additional variables. I edited answer. Please test and accept the answer if working.